# Why can't I add offset hours in datetime Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, datetime, datetimeoffset

I tried to add offset hours to my datetime object now,
but it doesn't show the added time that is actual time.
It is my flutter project in android studio.

```
    void getTime() async {
    Response response = await
    get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi');
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);

    print(offset);
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse('offset')));
    print(now);
    }
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTime();
    }
```

This is the result I got:
[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz4Yp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Yayyy!

```
  void getTime() async {

    //Make the request
    Response response = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi');
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);


    //Get properties from data
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
    //print(datetime);
    print(offset);

    //create DateTime Object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
    print(now);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    getTime();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

1. You should pass `offset` to int.parse instead of `'offset'`
2. `add` is an immutable operation on a `DateTime` object. It does not change the `DataTime` object but returns a new one.

Try this instead:

````
DateTime dateTimeAfterOffset = DateTime.parse(datetime).add(
  Duration(
    hours: int.parse(offset),
  ),
);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Will help you with any kind of offset here is the example code below**

```
void getTime() async {
    var httpsUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'http',
        host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
        path: '/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata');

    Response response = await get(httpsUri);
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //print('data is ${response.body}');
    //get properties from data
    String dateTime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'];
    offset = offset.replaceAll("+", "");

    /// String offset1 = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    print('date=>$dateTime,offset=>$offset');

    //date time object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
    print('Final date before:$now');
    now = now.add(Duration(
        hours: int.parse(offset.split(':')[0]),
        minutes: int.parse(offset.split(':')[1])));
    print('Final date after:$now');
}
```